# C++ read/write of vector to binary file returning different data

Tags: c++, vector, file-io

I have a variable `W` which is a `vector<vector<vector< double > > >`, which I am writing to a binary file, then reading back in.

However, the data I read back in is different than the data I've written out, and I don't know why.

The reading in and out does not crash or anything, so I assume its reading valid data in valid locations, but the values are just different. Any ideas how to rectify this?

BTW, my intention is that the outputted file overwrite any existing file of the same name, so that only the most recent file is available.

```
void output_W(string filename){
    
    cout << "writing W file..." << endl;
    ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open(filename,ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<W.size(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<W[i].size(); ++j) {
            for (unsigned int k=0; k<W[i][j].size(); ++k) {
                output_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&W[i][j][k]),sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }
    output_file.close();
    cout << "finished writing W file" << endl;
};

void input_W(string filename){
    
    cout << "reading W file..." << endl;
    ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open(filename,ios::in | ios::binary);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<W.size(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<W[i].size(); ++j) {
            for (unsigned int k=0; k<W[i][j].size(); ++k) {
                input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&W[i][j][k]),sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }
    input_file.close();
    cout << "finished reading W file" << endl;
};
```

Comment: When you call `input_W` are all of the vectors already resized? Normally I'd expect an output function to write the sizes and and input function to read them from the file and resize the containers. Can you flesh this out to a [mcve]?

Comment: Just an FYI, the innermost `for` loops can be replaced by a single call to `write()` and `read()`, eg: `for (unsigned int k=0; k<W[i][j].size(); ++k) { output_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&W[i][j][k]),sizeof(double)); }` can be replace with `output_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(W[i][j].data()), W[i][j].size() * sizeof(double));`

Comment: Also, you are not validating that the file is actually being created/opened successfully, or written/read successfully. Maybe the `ifstream` creates the file OK, but the `ofstream` can't open it for reading? Or maybe `write()` is failing, or `read()` is failing. We don't know. Put some error checking into the code.

Comment: Thank you both Retired Ninja and Remy Lebeau for your input. Ive satisfied myself that the i/o code is working properly, both before and after Remy's suggestions. I believe the problem was in an entirely different part of the code but just expressed itself here. Yes excuse my lazy non-error-checking code! Thanks for your help!